# after form submit,if user already login then form will submit else login first then form should be submit automatically

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a form, if user already login then from will submit, else login first then form should be submit automatically with the help of cookie an error is sowing in my code on last move_uploaded_file.

My code is given as follows

```html
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])
 { 
$ad_title=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ad_title']);
$category=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
$sub_category=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['sub_category']);
$description=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$rent_amount=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['rent_amount']);
$rent_security=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['rent_security']);
$contact=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
$email=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$city=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$state=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
$area=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['area']);
$buy=(isset($_POST['buy'])?1:0);
$sell=(isset($_POST['sell'])?1:0);
$rent=(isset($_POST['rent'])?1:0);
$manufacture=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['company_name']);
$conditions=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['condition']);

$rent_option=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['rent_option']);

$a=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$path="image/product/$a";

$b=$_FILES['file2']['name'];
$path2="image/product/$b";

$c=$_FILES['file3']['name'];
$path3="image/product/$c";

$d=$_FILES['file4']['name'];
$path4="image/product/$c";

$e=$_FILES['file5']['name'];
$path5="image/product/$c";


if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
$query=$mysqli->query("insert into ads(product_name,category,sub_category,description,image_1,image_2,image_3,image_4,image_5,city,state,rent_amount,rent_option,security_amount,contact_no,email,area,buy,sell,rent,user_id,manufacture,conditions)values('$ad_title','$category','$sub_category','$description','$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$city','$state','$rent_amount','$rent_option','$rent_security','$contact','$email','$area','$buy','$sell','$rent','$user_id','$manufacture','$conditions')");
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path) & move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'],$path2) & move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file3']['tmp_name'],$path3) & move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file4']['tmp_name'],$path4) & move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file5']['tmp_name'],$path5);
if($query)
{

echo "success";
}
}else{ 


  $time = time() + 60;
  setcookie('email',$email,$time);
  setcookie('ad_title',$ad_title,$time);
  setcookie('category',$category,$time);
  setcookie('sub_category',$sub_category,$time);
  setcookie('description',$description,$time);
  setcookie('rent_amount',$rent_amount,$time);
  setcookie('rent_security',$rent_security,$time);
  setcookie('contact',$contact,$time);
  setcookie('city',$city,$time);
  setcookie('state',$state,$time);
  setcookie('area',$area,$time);
  setcookie('buy',$buy,$time);
  setcookie('sell',$sell,$time);
  setcookie('rent',$rent,$time);
  setcookie('manufacture',$manufacture,$time);
  setcookie('condition',$conditions,$time);
  
  setcookie('rent_option',$rent_option,$time);
   
   setcookie('file',$a,$time);
   setcookie('file2',$b,$time);
   setcookie('file3',$c,$time);
   setcookie('file4',$d,$time);
   setcookie('file5',$e,$time);
   
header("Location:product/login.php"); }
}
 
 if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])){
  
  $email =$_COOKIE['email'];
     $cookie2 = $_COOKIE['ad_title']; 
     $cookie3 = $_COOKIE['category'];
     $cookie4 = $_COOKIE['sub_category'];
     $cookie5 = $_COOKIE['description'];
     $cookie6 = $_COOKIE['rent_amount'];
     $cookie7 = $_COOKIE['rent_security'];
     $cookie8 = $_COOKIE['contact'];
     $cookie9 = $_COOKIE['city'];
     $cookie10 = $_COOKIE['state'];
     $cookie11 = $_COOKIE['area'];
     $cookie12 = $_COOKIE['buy'];
     $cookie13 = $_COOKIE['sell'];
     $cookie14 = $_COOKIE['rent'];
     $cookie15 = $_COOKIE['manufacture'];
     $cookie16 = $_COOKIE['condition'];
  $cookie17 = $_COOKIE['file'];
  $cookie18 = $_COOKIE['file2'];
     $cookie19 = $_COOKIE['file3'];
  $cookie20 = $_COOKIE['file4'];
  $cookie21 = $_COOKIE['file5'];
  $cookie22 = $_COOKIE['rent_option'];
  
  
  
$pat="image/product/$cookie17";
$pat2="image/product/$cookie18";
$pat3="image/product/$cookie19";
$pat4="image/product/$cookie20";
$pat5="image/product/$cookie21";
  
  
  
  
  
$query1=$mysqli->query("insert into ads(product_name,category,sub_category,description,image_1,image_2,image_3,image_4,image_5,city,state,rent_amount,rent_option,security_amount,contact_no,email,area,buy,sell,rent,user_id,manufacture,conditions)
values
('$cookie2','$cookie3','$cookie4','$cookie5','$cookie17','$cookie18','$cookie19','$cookie20','$cookie21',
'$cookie9','$cookie10','$cookie6','$cookie22','$cookie7','$cookie8',
'$email','$cookie11','$cookie12','$cookie13','$cookie14','$user_id','$cookie15','$cookie16')");
move_uploaded_file($cookie17,$pat)& 
move_uploaded_file($cookie18,$pat2)& 
move_uploaded_file($cookie19,$pat3)& 
move_uploaded_file($cookie20,$pat4)& 
move_uploaded_file($cookie21,$pat5);
  
  
  if($query1){
   
   echo "Succes";
  }
  else{
   echo "Something went wrong.";
  }
  
  
  }
  
 ?>
```

Comment: @shadow i have no idea about that what i have to do for this.

Comment: Where is your php code? Did you use session ?
or you want whole php code for this?

Comment: I suggest you use `if` then `else`

Comment: Check the session on form submit using ajax if the session is present then submit else stop the form being submitted and open a login box.

Comment: @Ajay Makwana - I have stored users_id in session variable.

Comment: Check if user logged in with your session and submit the form if not logged in popup login form and trigger appointment form submit after login.

Comment: just check IF(!isset($_SESSION['users_id'])){//redirect to Login}else{//do submit}

Comment: @Ajay Makwana - I have already applied if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){//login page} else {//submit}.

but when it redirected to login page and user do login it goes login  successfully ,  but not that form submitted which user filled first time.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to your question: You have no name assigned to your `select` menu.

That aside, you need to check for the existence of a session variable - assuming you set some sort of session variable when the user logged in? ie: `$_SESSION['username']='fred'` etc? You can generate javascript that will submit the form at page load.

```
<form name="appointment" method="POST" action="appointment.php" role="form">
    <!-- form contents -->
</form>

<?php
    if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
        echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                document.querySelectorAll( form['name=\"appointment\"]' )[0].submit();
            </script>";
    }
?>
```